# action listener doesnt work

Tags: java, swing

I am new in java swing unfortunately when i want to set action listener to one of the button that it has to get the textArea content and send that to another class it doesn't work in a way that i expect and instead it works when i change the text area's content, i don't know What's happened?

first button i named Button and the same problem happened when i use another action listener inside the Button's action listener named Clac

here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FFT_Main_Frame extends JFrame {

    JLabel label;
    JButton button;
    TextPanel txtPanel;
    JButton Button;
    JLabel label1;
    // JTextArea[] BoxArray;
    makePolynomial mp;
    JButton Calc;
    Complex[] Nums;
    Complex[] Result;
    int input;
    FFT_Main fft_main;
    ShowResult shr;

    public FFT_Main_Frame() {

        Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            // Test t;

            // Integer content;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {
                    Integer content = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(txtPanel.getTextArea()));
                    input = content;
                    System.out.println(input);
                    // inputt=input;
                    mp = new makePolynomial(content);
                    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    add(mp);
                    // setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    add(Calc);

                    Nums = new Complex[input + 1];
                    Calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                            for (int i = input; i >= 0; i--) {
                                Nums[i] = new Complex(Double.parseDouble(mp.BoxArray[2 * (i + 1) - 1].getText()),
                                        Double.parseDouble(mp.BoxArray[2 * i].getText()));
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++) {
                                System.out.println(Nums[i]);
                            }
                            fft_main = new FFT_Main();
                            Result = new Complex[input];

                            Result = fft_main.Recursive_FFT(Nums);

                            shr = new ShowResult(Result);

                            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                            add(shr, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                            System.out.println("Result\n\n");
                            for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++) {
                                System.out.println(Result[i]);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Just Numbers! ", "Wrong Value",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: So you example is likely to generate a `NullPointerException` as `Button` is never initalised, but your try and add an `ActionListener` to it. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using action listener wrong way here is an example how to use it

```
public FFT_Main_Frame() {

  JButton Button = new JButton("Button");
  Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

       try {

         // Code Here

       }catch(Exception e) {
          // Code Here 

      }
  });

  JButton Calc = new JButton("Calc");
  Calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

           // Code Here          

     }
     });

   }  
 }
```

Some tutorials on how to use action listener

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_action_listener.htm

Comment: thank you , for your comment but as a matter of fact  i wrote the code like this before but because i want the input value i couldn't do any thing except of putting the Calc action listener inside the Button action listener

Comment: you can get input this way what you want to do when button is clicked ?

Comment: you know as i wrote in the post when i clicked on the button i want to get the txtPanel value                                                     public class TextPanel extends JPanel {
 
 private JTextArea textArea;
 public TextPanel(){
  
  textArea=new JTextArea(1,3);
  
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  
  add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  //add(new JScrollPane(textArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);
 }
 
 String getTextArea()
 {
  return textArea.getText();
 }
}
but in the code that i wrote when i clicked on the button it doesn't work but when i want to clean the text area actionlistener acts

Comment: you can get Text  from this code txtPanel.getText();

Comment: if you want to get integer value you can use this code  int content = Integer.parseInt(txtPanel.getText());

Comment: yes at first it works and get the text area in that line but i am wondering why the reaming code do not execute but when i clean the text area it works i mean the line                                                                               mp = new makePolynomial(content);
                    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    add(mp);